# Tumblr Static Page, deleting inline CSS

Tags: html, css, customization, inline, tumblr

I am trying to create a couple of static pages on a Tumblr blog I am creating. However when using the html option for creating a static page, whenever I try to submit html with inline-styling Tumblr deletes it, for example

```
<div style="margin-top:35px;">
```

becomes

```
<div>
```

on submitting.

Is this just how Tumblr is set up or is there something I am missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tumblr will detele inline styling if you're using the Standard Layout, just switch to Custom Layout and you'll be able to write any HTML that you want

[image: Custom Layout]


Result here: http://dustyprophet.com/test

Comment: I realised this about 5 minutes after posting, it's not an ideal answer but it will do! 
Thanks for your quick response

Answer (score 0):

To be able to add inline CSS to posts you need to first change the default Text editor in the Tumblr settings... usually changing to a  Plain text/HTML as opposed to the RichText edit will do the trick.

After editing and publishing a post - it's probably useful to change the default text edit back to Richtext.